# What event to capture when a TreeVew node is checked/unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a node `cbNode5` in a TreeView that contains 5 child nodes and I am trying to somehow capture the checking and unchecking of `cbNode5` so I can mark the child nodes and check/unchecked to match the parent node. I know how to work though the nodes to check/uncheck the child nodes but what I can not figure out is what, and how to capture, the event that fires when the user checks the checkbox for a nod via either mouse click or keyboard.

I have tried the AfterCheck event but it does not seem to be working (and I do know the line to set the check box to true works as it runs fine under other events):

```
private void tvSteps_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    tvSteps.Nodes["cbStep1"].Checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [AfterCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) event...

The AfterCheck() event is working fine for me:

```
    private void tvSteps_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Name == "cbNode5")
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in e.Node.Nodes)
            {
                tn.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I check/uncheck cbNode5, its children check/uncheck to match it.

Are you sure the **key** you are using is correct?

Comment: I have tried the AfterCheck event with no success, edited question to include the AfterCheck code that I tested with.

Comment: @user1365911: You need to bind the event as appropriate. Coppying the snippet is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to note that I resolved this problem by going into my `TreeViewForm.Designer.CS`, `InitializeComponent` function and adding the following line into the properties of the treeview object causing the problem:

`this.treeView1.AfterCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.treeView1_AfterCheck);`

Note that your object names will differ from my own.
For some reason the `AfterSelect` event handler was added programatically to my form's Designer.CS file but my `AfterCheck` event handler was not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[TreeView.AfterCheck Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx)

Comment: I have tried the AfterCheck event with no success, edited question to include the AfterCheck code that I tested with.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this task, you can handle the TreeList.AfterCheckNode event and set the TreeListNode.Checked property manually. Here is a sample code snippet:

```
private void treeList1_AfterCheckNode(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.NodeEventArgs e)  
{  
   if (e.Node.ParentNode != null)  
      e.Node.ParentNode.Checked = IsAllChecked(e.Node.ParentNode.Nodes);  
   else  
      SetCheckedChildNodes(e.Node.Nodes);  
}  
private void SetCheckedChildNodes(TreeListNodes nodes)  
{  
    foreach (TreeListNode node in nodes)  
      node.Checked = node.ParentNode.Checked;  
}  
private bool IsAllChecked(DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNodes nodes)  
{  
    bool value = true;  
    foreach (TreeListNode node in nodes)  
    {  
        if (!node.Checked)  
        {  
           value = false;  
           break;  
        }  
     }  
     return value;  
}
```